# eclipse adt error after updating sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-tools

I updated the android sdk tools recently and now I am getting this error on starting Eclipse.

[image: Error update ADT]

When I check for updates, I get this.

[image: No Updates found]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: @Kailas I am using version 4.2

Comment: @matiash It is but I was not able to solve my problem from the answers given there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version is full of bugs.

[Google project manager said to use old  SDK 22.6.2 until the problem is fixed.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#makechanges)

> Please wait for an updated version within a day or two. Until then, your workaround is to do download one of:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
>   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip
>   and copy over the following files:
>   tools/hprof-conv
>   tools/support/annotations.jar
>   tools/proguard

So download the zip, after extracting the zip file you downloaded, paste(overwrite) its contents in the SDK to where it is installed. Then start eclipse it will work normally!

Comment: so should I paste all the content of the downloaded zip or just the three files mentioned?

Comment: I mean two files and one folder